# GitHub PR shows conflict but local does not

Tags: git, github, git-merge-conflict

I use 2 main branch, `master` and `release` branch. Every PR will be merged to `master` first, and after proper testing, I will raise a PR to merge from `master` to `release` branch. I will not raise any PRs to merge into `release` except from `master`.

Based on this workflow, `master` branch should be merged into `release` branch without any conflict. However, sometimes it will show *merge-conflict* in GitHub PR page, whereas I can merge `master` into `release` branch without conflict in my local environment.

I notice that GitHub contains 3 merge options, `simple merge`, `squash merge` and `rebase merge`. Is the *merge-conflict* caused by the merge options I choose? How to solve this weird *merge-conflict* in GitHub?

Thanks

Comment: With the workflow you are using, I would use the simple merge into release. Is that what you're doing? Otherwise, future merges will not be as easy to reconcile, which could explain the conflicts.

Comment: In general, you should only use squash or rebase merge from branches you plan to delete, e.g., feature branches, development branches, bug fix branches, that only live during the work it's been created for. Long lived branches, on the other hand, require simple merges, so the connections between them remain in the history.

Comment: In the most recent situation, I had used `squash merge` to merge other branches into `master` branch previously. However, when I raised a PR to merge `master` branch into `release` branch, GitHub showed *conflict* even if I chose `simple merge`. One more thing, GitHub fetched some old commits, which had been merged into `release` branch in previous PRs.

Comment: I think you need to look at your commit graph with a visual graph display. More GUI git apps will provide that, as it to show your all branches and the graph. Or one the command line: `git log --all --graph --decorate --format=oneline`. Hopefully when you see the global view, it'll make sense to you. Another suggestion: use `git fetch` to just get locally what's on the server. I avoid `git pull` in general, which is just fetch+merge, because I want to know what might get merged before I let it happen.

Comment: If GitJub showed a conflict now, it means something you did in the past introduced that conflict. Its past operations that brought about the conflict you see now. To see what's going on, do a `git fetch`, inspect the commit graph, and then locally do the same merge GitHub would do, but on your own machine. That way, you'll be able to see where the conflict lies. If you're still learning and you're not sure what you're doing, you might want to do it in a fresh sandbox, which you can throw away if you get confused.

Comment: But at this point, my overarching recommendation is to take the time to read and understand a decent Git tutorial. You're getting stuck on relatively basic stuff here, so I'm guessing you don't fully understand the Git model yet. Time invested in learning it in more depth will be well worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in GitHub.
This worked for me:

1. Merge locally
2. Push up the updated branch

   - This automatically closed (***merged***) the PR on GitHub

Comment: Do I need to *force-push* to GitHub? By the way, `master` and `release` branches have protection rule to prevent being committed directly.

Comment: @obelisk0114 yes. The given branch protection would need to be disabled temporarily to allow for the push.